# Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/serena/stable/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, docker, linux-mint

When I do sudo apt-get update I get the following error:

```
Err:23 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu serena/stable amd64 Packages 404 Not Found 
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/serena/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785768/docker-packages-for-stretch-release-failing-to-be-found-on-sudo-apt-get-update)

but still I am not able to solve the problem. I am running on

Distributor ID: LinuxMint

Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Release:    18.1

and the file /etc/apt/sources.list which seems to be important contains
the line

`#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib main non-free`

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update from a Mint release (Serena). If you look at https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/, you will see that it only supports the standard Ubuntu releases.

As we can see [here](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php), Serena is based on Xenial, so I think your best best is to change the relevant `sources.list` line and change `serena` to `xenial` (which isn't the line you've given us, btw)

For instance, I have `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable`. If you can't find the line in `/etc/apt/sources/list`, it could be in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Thank you and you are right I supplied the wrong line. The correct one was in the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list